# Inkscape, преобразовать текст в объект path

Tags: svg, inkscape

Предположим написал текст в редакторе Inkscape.
Как его теперь привести в один объект, в качестве path?

Все символы что есть, объединить и сделать на выходе как один объект в виде path.

Comment: В Кореле достаточно преобразовать текст в кривую и будет единый путь при экспорте в svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набираем в векторном редакторе слово, например: `Text`

- Выбираем шрифт, размер
  В пункте меню выбираем: **контур | оконтурить объект** или
  комбинация клавиш - <kbd>Ctrl + Shift +C</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем в формате `*.svg`
- Оптимизируем с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) для того чтобы убрать служебную
  информацию `Inkscape`
- Получился файл с четырьмя path (каждый path для одной буквы)

```css
.container {
 width:40vw;
 height:40vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <g aria-label="Text" style="line-height:13px;-inkscape-font-specification:'Adobe Garamond Pro'" id="text817" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="192" font-family="Adobe Garamond Pro" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none">
    <path d="M107.8 44.7c0-6.4-.2-6.5 5.6-6.5H127c10.6 0 17.9 1.5 22.3 4.8 2.9 2 4.2 9.2 4.8 14 1 1.1 4.2 1.1 5-.4-.6-5.8.8-21.3 2.9-29.2-.4-.8-2.5-1-3.5-.6-2.9 5-4.6 5.4-15 5.4H65.8c-8.9 0-15.2.2-16.3-6-.6-.5-3.1-.3-3.7 0-1.3 7.7-4.2 20-7.3 28.7.8 1.5 3.5 2.5 5 1.3 2.1-4.8 4-9 8.6-13.2 4.8-4.5 15.4-4.8 23.7-4.8h10.5c5.8 0 5.8.1 5.8 6.1v85.8c0 20.2-1 23-12 24l-6.8.6c-1.6 1-1.2 4.2 0 4.8a676 676 0 0 1 51.8 0c1.2-.6 1.5-4 .4-4.8l-6.2-.6c-11.1-1-11.5-3.8-11.5-24z" id="path4522"/>
    <path d="M201.5 109.8c8 0 10.8-.2 11.3-1.4.4-.7.8-2.3.8-5 0-11.5-10.7-22.8-27.2-22.8-23 0-38.6 19.8-38.6 43.4 0 8.4 2.3 17.5 8 25a34.4 34.4 0 0 0 27.9 12.6c10 0 23.8-4.8 30.1-17.8-.2-1.8-1.5-3-3.4-2.3-6 7.4-11.4 9.4-17.7 9.4-20.6 0-31.9-16.6-31.9-36 0-4.7.2-5.1 5.2-5.1zm-37.2-5.8c-1.4 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1 .2-6.3 10-16.7 21.3-16.7 11.2 0 14.8 6.8 14.8 12.1 0 2.5-.6 3.3-1.1 3.7-1.6 1.1-5.8 2-20 2z" id="path4524"/>
    <path d="M251.1 120.7c1.6 2.1 1.2 2.9-.5 5-4.4 5.4-13 18.2-17.1 22.5-3.5 3.6-6.2 5.2-9.6 5.7l-4.4.8c-1.4.8-1.2 4 .4 4.8a174.6 174.6 0 0 1 28.2 0c1.3-.6 1.5-3.8.4-4.8l-3.3-.6c-4.8-.7-4.4-2.3-.6-8.4l8-12.7c1.4-2.1 3-4 3.5-4.6.8.6 2 2.1 4.3 5.6l10 14.4c2.4 3.4 2.3 5.1-3.3 5.7l-5.6.6c-1.3 1-1 4.2.6 4.8a267.7 267.7 0 0 1 37.2 0c1.4-.6 1.6-3.6.4-4.8l-3-.2c-5.2-.4-8.3-2.9-12.7-9L266 120.3c-2.5-3.4-2.5-4-.2-7a172 172 0 0 1 18-22c2.2-1.7 5-2.3 9.7-3.2l2.9-.6c1.1-1 1.1-4-.4-4.8a157.8 157.8 0 0 1-28 0c-1.6.6-2 3.6-.8 4.8l2.3.6c4.2 1.1 4.8 2 1.5 7-4 6.2-10.4 15.8-11.1 16.4-.6-.6-1.7-2.1-2.5-3.3l-9.2-13.4c-3.3-4.6-3.5-5.8 1.7-6.7l2.9-.6c1.1-1 1.1-4-.2-4.8-7.5.4-11.7.6-16.3.6-4.8 0-9.3-.2-16.7-.6-1.4.6-1.6 3.8-.4 4.8l3 .6c5.4 1 8.7 4 11.6 8.2z" id="path4526"/>
    <path d="M356.3 91.3c1.7-1.1 2.1-6.3-.2-8h-21.3c-3.3 0-3.5-.2-3.5-3.7V71c-.7-1.4-3-1.4-4-1-2 3.9-5.6 9-8 11.4-2 1.7-6.8 4.2-12.3 6-.8 1-.6 3.2.5 4h5.4c3.8 0 4 .3 4 5.5v44c0 11.5 3.5 20.7 20 20.7 9.8 0 16.7-4.8 20.2-8.8.3-1.2-.4-3.3-2-3.3-.5 0-3 2.1-4.8 2.7-1.5.6-3.2 1-5.1 1-12.7 0-14-10.2-14-21.3v-36c0-4 .1-4.6 3.4-4.6z" id="path4528"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Соединяем 4 path**

Для этого в первый path добавляем в конец, после **z** содержание 2-го патча после символа **M**

***Итак получится один path с 4 буквами***

```css
.container {
 width:40vw;
 height:40vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <g aria-label="Text" style="line-height:13px;-inkscape-font-specification:'Adobe Garamond Pro'" id="text817" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-weight="400" font-stretch="normal" font-size="192" font-family="Adobe Garamond Pro" letter-spacing="0" word-spacing="0" fill="red" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none">
    <path d="M107.8 44.7c0-6.4-.2-6.5 5.6-6.5H127c10.6 0 17.9 1.5 22.3 4.8 2.9 2 4.2 9.2 4.8 14 1 1.1 4.2 1.1 5-.4-.6-5.8.8-21.3 2.9-29.2-.4-.8-2.5-1-3.5-.6-2.9 5-4.6 5.4-15 5.4H65.8c-8.9 0-15.2.2-16.3-6-.6-.5-3.1-.3-3.7 0-1.3 7.7-4.2 20-7.3 28.7.8 1.5 3.5 2.5 5 1.3 2.1-4.8 4-9 8.6-13.2 4.8-4.5 15.4-4.8 23.7-4.8h10.5c5.8 0 5.8.1 5.8 6.1v85.8c0 20.2-1 23-12 24l-6.8.6c-1.6 1-1.2 4.2 0 4.8a676 676 0 0 1 51.8 0c1.2-.6 1.5-4 .4-4.8l-6.2-.6c-11.1-1-11.5-3.8-11.5-24z
M201.5 109.8c8 0 10.8-.2 11.3-1.4.4-.7.8-2.3.8-5 0-11.5-10.7-22.8-27.2-22.8-23 0-38.6 19.8-38.6 43.4 0 8.4 2.3 17.5 8 25a34.4 34.4 0 0 0 27.9 12.6c10 0 23.8-4.8 30.1-17.8-.2-1.8-1.5-3-3.4-2.3-6 7.4-11.4 9.4-17.7 9.4-20.6 0-31.9-16.6-31.9-36 0-4.7.2-5.1 5.2-5.1zm-37.2-5.8c-1.4 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1 .2-6.3 10-16.7 21.3-16.7 11.2 0 14.8 6.8 14.8 12.1 0 2.5-.6 3.3-1.1 3.7-1.6 1.1-5.8 2-20 2z
M251.1 120.7c1.6 2.1 1.2 2.9-.5 5-4.4 5.4-13 18.2-17.1 22.5-3.5 3.6-6.2 5.2-9.6 5.7l-4.4.8c-1.4.8-1.2 4 .4 4.8a174.6 174.6 0 0 1 28.2 0c1.3-.6 1.5-3.8.4-4.8l-3.3-.6c-4.8-.7-4.4-2.3-.6-8.4l8-12.7c1.4-2.1 3-4 3.5-4.6.8.6 2 2.1 4.3 5.6l10 14.4c2.4 3.4 2.3 5.1-3.3 5.7l-5.6.6c-1.3 1-1 4.2.6 4.8a267.7 267.7 0 0 1 37.2 0c1.4-.6 1.6-3.6.4-4.8l-3-.2c-5.2-.4-8.3-2.9-12.7-9L266 120.3c-2.5-3.4-2.5-4-.2-7a172 172 0 0 1 18-22c2.2-1.7 5-2.3 9.7-3.2l2.9-.6c1.1-1 1.1-4-.4-4.8a157.8 157.8 0 0 1-28 0c-1.6.6-2 3.6-.8 4.8l2.3.6c4.2 1.1 4.8 2 1.5 7-4 6.2-10.4 15.8-11.1 16.4-.6-.6-1.7-2.1-2.5-3.3l-9.2-13.4c-3.3-4.6-3.5-5.8 1.7-6.7l2.9-.6c1.1-1 1.1-4-.2-4.8-7.5.4-11.7.6-16.3.6-4.8 0-9.3-.2-16.7-.6-1.4.6-1.6 3.8-.4 4.8l3 .6c5.4 1 8.7 4 11.6 8.2z
        M356.3 91.3c1.7-1.1 2.1-6.3-.2-8h-21.3c-3.3 0-3.5-.2-3.5-3.7V71c-.7-1.4-3-1.4-4-1-2 3.9-5.6 9-8 11.4-2 1.7-6.8 4.2-12.3 6-.8 1-.6 3.2.5 4h5.4c3.8 0 4 .3 4 5.5v44c0 11.5 3.5 20.7 20 20.7 9.8 0 16.7-4.8 20.2-8.8.3-1.2-.4-3.3-2-3.3-.5 0-3 2.1-4.8 2.7-1.5.6-3.2 1-5.1 1-12.7 0-14-10.2-14-21.3v-36c0-4 .1-4.6 3.4-4.6z"/>
    
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```